# Using markdown in wikidpad

Tags: wiki, markdown

I'm using [Wikidpad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) as a desktop wiki on the PC.

Is there any way I can use markdown syntax instead of wikidpad syntax? There's an option to select wiki language, but I don't know how to go about using the option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://trac.wikidpad2.webfactional.com/wiki/HowToCreateWikiLanguage20

Comment: @terdon I've tried it (copied file to user_extensions folder, renamed & edited as shown, restart wikidpad), but I didn't get another option to change the wiki language in the option box. I'm using wikidpad version 2.1_01.

Answer (score 1):

As the [link](http://trac.wikidpad2.webfactional.com/wiki/HowToCreateWikiLanguage20) from the Wikidpad help shows, you need to copy and edit the parsing file and placing it in the correct directory.

In the comment to the original question the OP mentioned that it wasn't working. I had the same issue and found that editing with Notepad didn't seem to actually save my changes. Editing with Visual Studio Code (in administrator mode) did.

A second issue is that the internal wiki name ("wikidpad_default_2_0") needs to be edited in the file. The name for that internal variable name needs to be in lower case otherwise I don't think Wikidpad will read it.